# How do I fix these errors when running the PHP Composer Installer?

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a server that was recently upgraded to PHP 5.3. Now when I try to [install composer](http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md), I get the following error messages:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: ffmpeg: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match
in Unknown on line 0
```

How do I fix these errors and get the installer to run properly?

Comment: recompile the module for the new php install. you can't mix api versions like that.

Comment: This has nothing to do with composer. FFMpeg extension is compiled against an old version of php. Remove it from php.ini (or /etc/php.d if your system puts extensions configs there)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be an invalid PHP module being installed, not something with the Composer installer.

Have you tried running a simple PHP script like

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

Does this work?